# How to remove extraneous edges

Tags: mesh

What is the best way to dissolve these edges? Dissolving does not seem to work at least on the edges on top.

[image]

Comment: Blender cant handle face (or n-gons) wit a hole, so one edge like one on left side will be kept ... but the rest should dissolve (only in case one of them is not part of split bottom face hole :) ).

Comment: Blender doesn't allow holes, so you won't be able to dissolve all of the edges, but you should be able to easily dissolve the two that are on the side.  Not sure there's a 'best' way, but I would uses edge slide to move them to the corners and then merge by distance to remove the extra vertices.

Comment: I see. So the mesh has to be continuous.